# RE - Laravel: Auto fill input after selecting value from dropdown

Tags: ajax, laravel, dropdown

Im having trouble to retrieve data into input box right after user select from dropdown. Any suggestion? Last suggest was not working.

internalaudit.blade.php

```php
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('text', 'Doc No', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) !!}
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <select name="docNo" id="docNo" class="form-control" style="width:250px">

                    @foreach ($soplists as $soplist)
                    <option value="{{ $soplist->id }}">{{ $soplist->doc_no }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>




        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rev_no" id="rev_no">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
```

Ajax

```
 <script>
     $('#docNo').change(function() {
         var id = $(this).val();
         var url = '{{ route("getDetails", ":id") }}';
         url = url.replace(':id', id);

         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'get',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(response) {
                 if (response != null) {
                     $('#rev').val(response.rev_no);
                     $('#title').val(response.title);
                 }
             }
         });
     });
```

Controller

```php
 public function internalAudit()
    {

        /*Generate number*/
        $query = Cars::latest()->first(); //get last query
        $validators = User::all();
        $departments =  Department::all();
        $isolists =  isoList::all();
        $soplists =  sopList::all();

        $ex = explode('/', $query['iaCarRefNo']); //explode last number from DB

        $type = strtoupper(Request::segment(2)); //get type from url

        if (empty($query->iaCarRefNo)) {
            $number = '1';
            $nextNumber = 'PLW' . '/' . date('y') . $type . '/' . sprintf("%03d", $number);
        } else {
            $number = $ex[2] + 1;
            $nextNumber = 'PLW' . '/' . date('y') . $type . '/' . sprintf("%03d", $number);
        }


        return view('cars.internalaudit', compact('nextNumber', 'validators', 'departments', 'isolists', 'soplists'));
    }


    public function getDetails($id = 0)
    {
        $data = sopList::where('doc_no', $id)->first();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Route

```php
Route::get('get/details/{id}', 'internalAuditController@getDetails')->name('getDetails');

Route::get('/internalaudit', 'internalAuditController@internalAudit');

Route::post('/internalaudit', ['as' => 'internalaudit.store', 'uses' => 'internalAuditController@store']);
```

Database sop_list table image link

https://ibb.co/SwkJhLc

Dropdown and input image

https://ibb.co/0VN3Z2y

Network tab

https://ibb.co/56w5BLD

Comment: The value is 'Null' in network tab

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error??

Comment: @anikislamShojib No errors. I'm able to retrieve data in dropdown list but after selected value the next input box remains blank which it suppose to retrieve doc_no and title from selected row.

Comment: Can you share your json response ? and you can use laravel HTTP Responses $this->response($data)  instead of echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @Casper Here's the js response https://ibb.co/yPdVJqz

Comment: @Steven go to network tab -> select XHR -> find your request and click on it then you will see json response

Comment: Okay here is your problem you have two errors to fix them import jquery and datetimepicker on your blade file

Comment: user dd($data) in you getDetails funtion and dump the output image

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta https://ibb.co/vchYp8z Yeah here's the output :(

Comment: @Steven it means data is not available with doc_id 3 in `sopList` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Accoding to your `console.log` there are 2 errors `$.ajax is not function` and `$.(...) datetimepicker is not function` beacuse of those errors, now your ajax does not work therefore you need to fix those issues first. Once you fix those issues you will be able to send ajax request and update input fileds.

To fix first problem, download the regular (compressed or not) version of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery) and include it in your project.

To fix second problem, download relevant datetimepicker and include in your project same like jQuery.

After that update `#rev` selector to `#rev_no`

```
$('#rev_no').val(response.rev_no);
```

Also use laravel [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses) instead `echo json_encode();`

```
return response()->json($data);
```

In your table there is no record for `doc_no = 3`, in your blade you're using `$soplist->id`

```
<option value="{{ $soplist->id }}">{{ $soplist->doc_no }}</option>
```

So do the same thing on controller,

```
$data = sopList::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Or

```
 $data = sopList::find($id);
```

Comment: Done but still same! the input fields are blank.. https://ibb.co/Nn6MJvx

Comment: and i getting null value :(

Comment: Can you dd($id, $data) before echo json_encode($data); and check output ?

Comment: Now ajax problem is fixed in your db there is no record for doc_no = 3 https://ibb.co/SwkJhLc so change $data = sopList::where('id', $id)->first();

Answer (score 0):

You gave a wrong id to response, also you should give an id to title input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
```

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change','#docNo',function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = '{{ route("getDetails", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);
    $.ajax({
             type: 'get',
             url: url,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(response) {
              $('#rev_no').val(response.rev_no);
              $('#title').val(response.title);

             }
         });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: did you change your script and clear the cache? i edited my answer. can you please try again

Comment: can you please console.log your response and show us?